# NetBeans with NBAndroid - cannot find symbol setContentView(R.layout.main);

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I recently installed NetBeans 7.1.1 with NBAndroid 1.11 plugin. After starting a new HelloWorld project, I get the following error from the test code:

> C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld\src\Hello\World\HelloWorldMain.java:14:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           setContentView(R.layout.main);

Here is my source code for HelloWorldMain.java file:

```
package Hello.World;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloWorldMain extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

The setContentView function is causing the problem for some reason. I checked the R.java file for any errors and didn't seem to find any:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package Hello.World;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f030000;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

You need to remove `import android.R;`. Your `R` and `android.R` are two different classes.

Comment: Wow, before I got an error that said I needed to add import android.R. Now it works without it.

Answer (score 10):

In Android, we dont have a class that is auto-generated, so, if you doesnt find your R class try to build your project or to run it. After that you can find that a new package was added to your project, there is where you can find your R class.